# How to enable keyboard keypress sounds on Windows 10 System?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, clicking-sound

Is there any way to enable Keyboard sounds on windows 10? Any way I could enable keypress sounds?

I have DELL XPS laptop with Windows 10.

Comment: Penteract Keyboard-Click Sounder on the Windows Store seems to do that. Maybe there are more on the store like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is [freeware along those lines](http://www.nattyware.com/qwertick.php).

I know pretty much nothing about the publisher so try at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out! Any way I could change the sound from typewriter to something else?

Comment: Could you please explain how to use that software to accomplish the task? I recommend looking at [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/380318)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to turn on filter keys in Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Keyboard or similar menu.

Comment: I came here with the reverse problem - trying to stop the keyboard clicking that somehow turned itself on. It seems I had accidentally activated filter keys, which can be toggled by holding the right shift button for eight seconds.